# Error: Lambda list with dots are only allowed in macros, not here : LIST?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am writing a function called `flatten` that is supposed to take the list that have embedded list and returns a simplified version of it . When I try to execute my function I get an error, stating "Lambda list with dots are only allowed in macros, not here: LIST" Any suggestions on how I can go about resolving this issue?

This is currently what I have.

```
(defun flatten list 
    (cond 
        (null list)'()
            (list (first list))
            (append (flatten (first list))
                    (flatten (rest list)))
        (cons (first list (flatten (rest list))))))
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a symbol name; it already has a value, and this will hide that.

Comment: @ScottHunter In Common Lisp functions and variables (and other things) are in different namespaces, so it's perfectly fine to use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: The [syntax of `defun`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm) involves an [ordinary lambda list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_da.htm): the symbol `list` is not a list, let alone an ordinary lambda list.  There are other things wrong here too.

Comment: It's a poor error message from CLISP, btw.

Comment: @jkiiski: Whereby "fine" you mean it works, but is needlessly confusing to read (especially if `list` were was bound to a lambda).

Comment: @ScottHunter It's pretty standard style in CL. I think you're thinking about Scheme. In CL, if you have a function in a variable called `list`, you would call it like `(funcall list args...)`, instead of `(list args...)`.

Comment: @ScottHunter So, don't use bad names (like `list` for a function). However, if your argument is a generic list, it makes sense to call it `list` (not `lst`, or `l`).

Answer (score 4):

## Lambda List

The argument list for a [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) should be an [Ordinary Lambda List](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_da.htm) (e.g., `(list)` in your case), not an atom `list`:

```
(defun flatten (list)
  ...)
```

## Cond

Your [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) is wrong.
The correct syntax is

```
(cond (condition1 form11 form12 ...)
      (condition2 form21 form22 ...)
      ...)
```

E.g.:

```
 (defun select-options ()
   (cond ((= a 1) (setq a 2))
         ((= a 2) (setq a 3))
         ((and (= a 3) (floor a 2)))
         (t (floor a 3)))) =>  SELECT-OPTIONS
 (setq a 1) =>  1
 (select-options) =>  2
 a =>  2
 (select-options) =>  3
 a =>  3
 (select-options) =>  1
 (setq a 5) =>  5
 (select-options) =>  1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses aren't balanced properly; `(null list)'())` closes the enclosing `cond`, which your indentation suggests is not what you want to do.

Comment: I took your suggestion and have revised accordingly. When I test again I still get the same error. Am I still overlooking something?

Comment: Clearly, but it is hard to tell what you are trying to express in your code, and thus difficult to say how to express it properly.